# Solving System of Congruences

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Solve

$x^{} \equiv 5 \pmod {7}$

$x^{} \equiv 5 \pmod {9}$

$x^{7} \equiv 5 \pmod {32}$

This is what I have done so far:

$x=7k+5$

Substitute in x in the second congruence statement

$7k+5 \equiv 5 \pmod {9}$

Solving this results in 
$k \equiv 0 \pmod {9}$

then

$k=9j$

$x=63j+5$

I'm lost from here on. I don't know how to deal with the $x^7$ congruence statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Euler's totient theorem, for all odd integer $x$:
$$x^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{32}$$

Trivially, $x$ is odd, for if $x$ is even, then so would be $x^7$.

Then,
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
x^7 \equiv 5 & \pmod{32} \\
(x^7)^7 \equiv 13 & \pmod{32} \\
x^{49} \equiv 13 & \pmod{32} \\
x^{16\times3+1} \equiv 13 & \pmod{32} \\
(x^{16})^3 \cdot x \equiv 13 & \pmod{32} \\
(1)^3 \cdot x \equiv 13 & \pmod{32} \\
x \equiv 13 & \pmod{32} \\
\end{array}$$

You should be able to continue now.

Comment: Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html, $$\lambda(32)=2^{5-2}=8$$  Now for $(x,2)=1$ $$x^8\equiv1\pmod{32}$$  $$\implies x^{-1}\equiv x^7\equiv5\iff x\equiv5^{-1}\equiv13$$